# How can I convert this flat json data into D3 hierarchical json data?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this data

```
    {
    "vision": [
        "ForwhoisathatunlikeourproductCarPooling",
        "ForwhoisathatunlikeourproductCarPooling"
    ],
    "actors": [
        "sddbbfcjwdfcc",
        "kjbkjjkbkjb"
    ]
}
```

which I want to convert in to hierarchical data which can be used with d3.js.

This is where I am trying to fit my data. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2966094. The expected structure of the json data is like

```
    {
  "name": "Clifford Shanks",
  "born": 1862,
  "died": 1906,
  "location": "Petersburg, VA",
  "parents": [
    {
      "name": "James Shanks",
      "born": 1831,
      "died": 1884,
      "location": "Petersburg, VA",
      "parents": [
        {
          "name": "Robert Shanks",
          "born": 1781,
          "died": 1871,
          "location": "Ireland/Petersburg, VA"
        },
        {
          "name": "Elizabeth Shanks",
          "born": 1795,
          "died": 1871,
          "location": "Ireland/Petersburg, VA"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Ann Emily Brown",
      "born": 1826,
      "died": 1866,
      "location": "Brunswick/Petersburg, VA",
      "parents": [
        {
          "name": "Henry Brown",
          "born": 1792,
          "died": 1845,
          "location": "Montgomery, NC"
        },
        {
          "name": "Sarah Houchins",
          "born": 1793,
          "died": 1882,
          "location": "Montgomery, NC"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Provide example of the resulting object, not everyone has idea what *" hierarchical data which can be used with d3.js"* is.

Comment: @dfsq : I have updated my question with the resulting object. Please have a look.

Comment: Your initial data is confusing. There should be a hierarchy of what exactly? Can you provide an example where your inital data has a parent and a child. Right now i just see an object with two arrays

Comment: @user1695032 : this is how I am getting the data from my request. Should I change the way I am getting this data?

Comment: Please show the hierarchical of your data. We don't see any clue of the parents and children here.

Comment: @Envil : This is the current structure of json I have 

{

   "value": {

      "name": "For  who   is a  that  unlike  our product Car Pooling ",

      "parents": [

         "{name : sddbbfcjwdfcc}",

         "{name :  kjbkjjkbkjb}"

      ]

   }

}